# LWC returning array

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

Hi i need to search and filter out all the values from the array with the help of the user input as a key , i am trying to use filter but not getting anything kindly help me out:

```
this.valueFromUser='987756467'

[
   {
      "ABC":"yyu678yut76u",
      "custui":"009686758jbnvnvm",
      "CAR__c":"YUI",
      "RAF__C":f,
      "FAN__C":"987756467",
      "WNNM__c":"TEDR",
      "TRR__C":"ytut",
      "FA__C":"hgythgjd000jghgj",
      "FA_C":"0",
      "M__c":"No"
      
   },
   {
      "ABC":"yyu678yut76u",
      "custui":"009686758jbnvnvm",
      "CAR__c":"YUI",
      "RAF__C":f,
      "FAN__C":"6768595758",
      "WNNM__c":"TEDR",
      "TRR__C":"yuyigjg",
      "FA__C":"hgythgjd000jghgj",
      "FA_C":"0",
      "M__c":"No"
   }
]
```

filter i am using:

```
const FAD = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(asd)).filter(x => x.id === this.valueFromUser);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter method expects an exact match precisely. Instead, use a regular expression. Here's an example I wrote on playground some time ago. The main point is you need a separate array to track all the data versus the current data.

```
<template>
    <lightning-input type="search" label="Search" onchange={updateSearch}>
    </lightning-input>
    <lightning-datatable data={data} columns={columns} key-field="id">
    </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    _allData = [
        { id: '1', Name: 'Marc Benioff',  MoeId:'3434'},
        { id: '2', Name: 'PEPE', MoeId:'5564'},
        { id: '3', Name: 'SAM', MoeId:'7767'},
        { id: '4', Name: 'Arnold Schwarzenegger', MoeId:'5544' }
    ];
    data = [];
    columns = [
        { label: 'People I Have Heard Of', fieldName: 'Name'},
        { label: 'Moe Id', fieldName: 'MoeId'},
    ];
    connectedCallback() {
        this.data = [...this._allData];
    }
    updateSearch(event) {
        var regex = new RegExp(event.target.value,'gi')
            this.data = this._allData.filter(
                row => regex.test(row.MoeId)
            );

        if(this.data.length == 0 ){
             this.data = this._allData.filter(
                row => regex.test(row.Name)
             );
        }
            
        
    }
}
```